# How do I divide values across dataframes in pandas?

Tags: pandas, division

So I have an original data set:
[original_data_set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J3Cf.png)

That I read in from a csv file and then separate according to field:

like so, `loan_df = re_df.loc[re_df.field == 'loan_amount'] home_df = re_df.loc[re_df.field == 'home_value']`

which yields
[loans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlY0I.png)
[home_vals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xV0x.png)

I want to divide across the value field over both dataframes however when I try, `ltv_df = loan_df['value']/home_df['value']` , I get a series of NaN values.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why make them separate datasets, as opposed to two columns in a single dataset?

Comment: `re_df.groupby('loan_id')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index()` ??

Comment: yeah, that's a much cleaner solution Nk03 thanks! Anyone happen to know why my code results in nan values?

Comment: When performing many operations, `pandas` tries to align values to the index. When the indexes are mismatched you'll end up with NaN values. In this case `ltv_df = loan_df.reset_index(drop=True)['value'] / home_df.reset_index(drop=True)['value']` would have worked because the indexes would have aligned. This assumes, of course that you want direct row by row division. The way I did in my answer (setting the index to the loan_id to ensure that like loan_ids are divided) is much safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

If just the [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas-dataframe-values) are needed numpy division works:

```
ltv_df = loan_df['value'].values / home_df['value'].values
```

```
[0.57238284 1.30293486]
```

Or if a DataFrame is needed use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index), divide then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) to get back to a DataFrame:

```
ltv_df = (
        loan_df.set_index('loan_id')['value'] /
        home_df.set_index('loan_id')['value']
).reset_index(name='result')
```

```
   loan_id    result
0        1  0.572383
1        2  1.302935
```

---

Alternatively the values can be obtained directly from the initial DataFrame via [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) and [`np.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html#numpy-divide):

```
ltv_df = (
    re_df.groupby('loan_id')['value'].apply(lambda x: np.divide(*x))
        .reset_index(name='result')
)
```

```
   loan_id    result
0        1  0.572383
1        2  1.302935
```

---

DataFrame Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

re_df = pd.DataFrame({'loan_id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                      'field': ['loan_amount', 'home_value'] * 2,
                      'value': [65037, 113625, 84395, 64773]})

loan_df = re_df.loc[re_df.field == 'loan_amount']
home_df = re_df.loc[re_df.field == 'home_value']
```